# Obtain data from clipboard using python

Tags: python, web, pyperclip

I am looking forward to copy data from a website to clipboard and pasting it into the Google sheet using python. Is there anyway to do that? I am not using web scraping since the website does not allow scraping, but it does allow to copy data to clipboard.

Comment: You can use the `clipboard` library..

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyperclip import paste
    
s = paste()
print(s)
```